# Keyboard with black and white keys all the same size and in-line?

Tags: theory, scales, keyboard

I want to know if anyone makes a chromatic keyboard on which sharps/flats are black, but the same size as the other keys and in line with them (see sketch below). There needs to be no distinction other than color between the keys.

Needs at least (ideally exactly) 2 octaves from C to C. Acoustic, electric, or even a phone app would be useful.

UPDATE: This is not intended to be an instrument for playing music, but a tool for learning music theory.
From there, you could learn piano simply by adjusting to the smaller black keys, or apply the concepts to other instruments.

[image: Drawing of desired keyboard layout]

Comment: What's your sense of why this "modified" keyboard would be better for learning than a standard one?

Comment: I can understand that this layout does not distinguish "black" from "white" keys, _except_ by color, in contrast to the usual physical piano/keyboard layout. Maybe giving equality to all half-steps, rather than giving some accidental priority to C-major scale? And, yes, I'm accustomed to the regular piano layout, and not this, but it seems more vertigo-inducing than the usual. :)

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt this exists - anywhere in this universe!

1. You can not even span an octave with one single hand, if the keys are about the same size as regular keys.
2. You will never be able to play from sheet or without looking at the keys.
3. You will miss the ability to *feel* where your fingers are. And this is a really important aspect for the part of your brain, that controls movements subconsciously. Your brain - not you consciously, but your *that part* of you brain needs this feeling to guide your movements. You can not play an instrument entirely consciously, that costs way too much resources.

There are certainly more severe disadvantages, but these are already enough for me to be certain, that no such key set exists.

Comment: i agree, your hands would need to be enormous just to play octaves. I can just about manage tenths on a regular keyboard. I could not even do an octave on that design.

Comment: first of all you can make all keys the same width as the black keys - then it would be no problem with spanning. I don't think you will loose any ability to feel where you are - there is no such problem on a guitar, why there would be such a problem with piano in this case?

Answer (score 2):

As Peder said, it might not exist...

... But then, why not make one ?

Starting from a standard electronic keyboard, all the white keys are spaced as you want. Without recommending any software, it is possible to *remap* the midi signals of these keys to a different note, for instance having some of them triggering sharp or flat, hence mimicking the behaviour of the black keys. In midi you can actually map anything to everything and, in particular, a note to another one.

Then, if you get the good map, all the white keys will behave chromatically as you want. If you want the flats/sharps to be black you can actually paint them if you do not mind sacrificing the keyboard you started with.

Comment: just get a cheap extension keyboard?

Comment: @bigbadmouse Yeah, whatever can output midi…